# Magento 2 InstallData SOLID principles

Tags: magento2, installdata

I have to add about `100 attributes` to product, but the file length is about `3000 lines`.In installer I only add new `attribute set, attribute group and attributes`.

I have attributes data in separate method that only `return multidimensional array (length 2900 lines)`.

Should I separate this attribute configuration in any way, if yes then how?